# calling individual nodes using SOAP XML response with namespaces styling in XSLT

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

i have been using XML and calling nodes individually without a hassle and now that i am wokring with a soap response i cant seem to get the XSLT to work. I need a way to enable me to call all nodes and style the XML as I chose in a Table or Div tags respectively.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessRequestTrans43Response xmlns="https://secure.transunion.co.za/TUBureau">
      <ProcessRequestTrans43Result>
        <RawData />
        <ResponseStatus>Success</ResponseStatus>
        <ProcessingStartDate>2015-12-21T10:37:09.6260543+02:00</ProcessingStartDate>
        <ProcessingTimeSecs>1.6709999999999998</ProcessingTimeSecs>
        <UniqueRefGuid>f3e76769-5b1f-44ae-82ff-3c7f96f4fd7a</UniqueRefGuid>
        <AddressNA08>
          <AddressNA08>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20151118</InformationDate>
            <Line1>52 CORLETT DR</Line1>
            <Line2>WANDERERS OFFICE PARK</Line2>
            <Suburb>ILLOVO</Suburb>
            <City>JOHANNESBURG</City>
            <PostalCode>2196</PostalCode>
            <ProvinceCode>GP</ProvinceCode>
            <Province>GAUTENG</Province>
            <AddressPeriod>00</AddressPeriod>
            <OwnerTenant />
            <AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged>
          </AddressNA08>
          <AddressNA08>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20120109</InformationDate>
            <Line1>MABETSHE ADMIN AREA</Line1>
            <Line2>MTHATHA</Line2>
            <Suburb />
            <City>UMTATA</City>
            <PostalCode>5100</PostalCode>
            <ProvinceCode>EC</ProvinceCode>
            <Province>EASTERN CAPE</Province>
            <AddressPeriod>03</AddressPeriod>
            <OwnerTenant />
            <AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged>
          </AddressNA08>
        </AddressNA08>
        <AKANamesNK04>
          <AKANamesNK04>
            <RecordSeq>01</RecordSeq>
            <Part>001</Part>
            <PartSeq>01</PartSeq>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20101215</InformationDate>
            <AKAName>NONDLOBO,ZANILE</AKAName>
          </AKANamesNK04>
          <AKANamesNK04>
            <RecordSeq>02</RecordSeq>
            <Part>001</Part>
            <PartSeq>01</PartSeq>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>19980428</InformationDate>
            <AKAName>NONDLOBO,ZANELA</AKAName>
          </AKANamesNK04>
        </AKANamesNK04>
        </ProcessRequestTrans43Result>
        </ProcessRequestTrans43Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is some of the soap response and my desired result can be seen [HERE](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3k/4). and my efforts for trying to get the Soap version working is [HERE](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go [solution](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/6) please check the surname tags aren't there in your xml , so i have mapped it to success for now you can do rest of the mapping yourself

Comment: is it possible to use a for each inside another one so that i can retrieve a node that is nested within another Node

Comment: Yes it is possible check here in the solution is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530495/nested-for-each-loops-in-xslt-not-working)